# Google PageSpeed Insights Prioritize visible content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagespeed

I am just doing some testing [on one of my random domains](http://mndyrs.com/sandbox/jsplayground/) and when I run the domain through [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmndyrs.com%2Fsandbox%2Fjsplayground%2F) with the following JavaScript being loaded:

```
$("[data-min-height]").each(function() {
     var dataHeight = $(this).data("min-height");
     var dataPercent = dataHeight / 100;
     $(this).css("min-height", function() {
          return $(window).height() * dataPercent;
     });
});
```

I get the error **Prioritize visible content**. If I take away the JavaScript, I no longer get the error. I am using [matthiasmullie/minify](https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify) to compress all my JavaScript together. Currently I have [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), [PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center](https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center), and [liabru/jquery-match-height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). Everything is compiled into one file called path.js. I load that file right before the closing body element and I use defer.

So if anyone has any ideas as to why the above JavaScript would cause this error on PageSpeed, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you might me inserting this JS code block in `<head>`?

Comment: Nope, it is in the path.js file (which is loaded right before the closing body element). <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/path.js" defer></script> That is why I do not get it, cause its with the rest of the javascript (jQuery, MatchHeight, etc...) at the bottom.

Comment: try dynamically creating the `script` element, assigning `type` and `src` to it and then finally appending it to the `head` of the document. `<script>var el=document.createElement('script'); el.src="scripts/path.js"; el.type="text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);</script>`

Comment: I added your code at the bottom of the page (right before the closing body element) but I still had the same error on PageSpeed (Prioritize visible content). I did also remove the JavaScript posted and reran the test, and no longer got the error. So it has to be something with that code, maybe the each loop, idk?

Comment: I removed <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/path.js" defer></script>  and replaced it with your code. I am using Chrome and there are no console errors.

Comment: can you do one more thing? copy all the contents of `path.js` and embed in the document itself in `<script>` tag

Comment: Put defer on it or not?

Comment: no don't put `defer`

Comment: I put <script defer><?php echo file_get_contents('scripts/path.js'); ?></script> and it worked! Thank you!!! 100/100 on PageSpeed!

Comment: With defer or without, still get 100/100, kinda odd.

Comment: without putting `defer` it works or not?

Comment: its not odd, I'm gonna post it as answer. so future refererrs might get it easily by seeing the answer and not reading comments one by one

Comment: Alright, well thank you very much! Could not understand why it would not work! Guess it did not have anything to do with the JavaScript code I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88231/discussion-between-antfuentes87-and-rohit-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

Embed all the contents of `path.js` directly in your HTML document.

[Read here about Prioritizing Visible Content](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent#structure)

you scripts might be used to render contents

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error was because of jQuery each function. I rebuilt the same thing, but only using a JavaScript for loop (no jQuery) and the error went away.

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("[data-min-height]");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var currentWindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var dataHeight = arr[i].dataset.minHeight;
    var dataPercent = dataHeight / 100;
    var dataPercentHeight = currentWindowHeight * dataPercent;
    arr[i].style.minHeight=dataPercentHeight + "px";
}
```