# Deferring images using only JavaScript doesn't eliminate PageSpeed warning

Tags: javascript, image, pagespeed, deferred-loading

In order to defer images, I implemented the solution [Patrick Sexton](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html) provides on his website but without luck so far!

It does not eliminate the "Prioritize visible content" warning in PageSpeed Insights

My HTML is:

```
<img class="slideshow-item active"
src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" 
data-src="images/....jpg" 
width="1982" height="954" alt="1" title="1" />
```

My JS is:

```
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Please tell use the symptoms or better: show us in a [mcve] - you can use lorempixel to get images to show. You have not posted any JavaScript nor provided any errors from the console

Comment: @mplungjan All I was expecting to happen is the elimination of the "Prioritize visible content" warning in PageSpeed Insights instead, nothing changed.

Comment: That is information you did not supply. So the defer works but the "PageSpeed" warning does not go away? Is that your issue?

Comment: @mplungjan Correct! The images load as I want.  The JS is placed just before the </body> and no error appears in the console and the warning is still there (PSI)

Comment: I fixed your question tell use what you want - it was an X/Y problem before

Comment: @mplungjan That's fine but what about the issue? For further information here is the [link](https://jimmydance.com/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135488/discussion-between-jim-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278388/google-pagespeed-insights-prioritize-visible-content

Comment: @mplungjan Well, it's not! In my case, I'm not using JQ at all. So the question remains: "Why deferring images (using only JavaScript) doesn't eliminate PageSpeed warning?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique specified in your Patrick Sexton article is not same as the Lazy Loading of images! in lazy loading, we should monitor scroll position and load only images which come into view. But, as mentioned in that article, the method used here by you, only **defer** the loading of (specified) images to **immediately after the initial page load**.

In other words, all images will be loaded without user interaction, but it only try to load main content (like as html, css, js and important images that you didn't applied their source by `data-src`) and after them, start loading the rest of images.

If you know what you choose to implement, the PageSpeed Insights warning is not important for your case. each method has its own advantages and usages. as it is written in referenced article, a main disadvantage of lazy loading could be:

> The most common reason people may chose not to defer images via lazy loading is likely the new popular trend of having one-page templates.

in one-page applications, the main navigation is not taking you to other pages, it just taking you to different parts of the same page. Your page loads, the user sees your main navigation, and if they click, they are taken to part of your page that does not have the images loaded yet (which is not so good).

the provided technique omit such problem.

Comment: The same information is everywhere on the internet as well as in Patrick's Sexton website! No need for you to repeat, though... I'd appreciate an explanation or even the solution.

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me, i think i explained it. So whats your question? And solution for what? Your code works as its expected

Comment: The question is: Why deferring images (using only JavaScript) doesn't eliminate PageSpeed "Prioritize Visible Content" warning?

Comment: and as i said, the answer is: the method choose by  you, is such that it defer image loading partially, just after page content loaded (called by: `window.onload = init;`). Your method does not post pone image loading to later time when user scrolls the page to the position of images... and That PSI warning just consider this full lazy type of deferment! you should not rely on that warning if you need and choose the Patrick method. for full lazy load, you should use [methods like described here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/) as you probably know.

Comment: also check this: [Why you Shouldn’t Care About Google PageSpeed Insights](https://blog.wp-rocket.me/the-truth-about-google-pagespeed-insights/)